# how does fwrite copy data in a file when it's a structure

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

here are my structures

```
typedef struct buffer
{
    char tab[b];
    int suiv;
}buffer;
typedef struct header
{
    int first ;
    int nb_buff ;
    int nb_insert ;
    int nb_supp ;
    int last ;
    int pos ;

}header;
```

So I need to copy these structures in a binary file ,and then retrieve them afterward to make some treatments on them ,however I struggled to understand how fwrite and fread worked when the data given is a structure ,can anyone help me understand ?

Answer (score 1):

the structure is represented in the memory as a chunk of data. That chunk is `sizeof(your_structure)` bytes long. It contains all members and padding.

`fwrite` simple writes this chunk of memory to the file.

`fread`  reads this data from the file and stores in memory "reacreating" the structure as the layout it's memory layout is the same

Comment: thank you for your answer however what I want to understand is how these structures are copied,I mean are they copied one by one (for example for the header does the function copy each integer apart: first then nb_buff...pos)?

Comment: Yes, the struct members will be in that same order of declaration, the fwrite and fread will handle it as block of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the declaration of `fwrite`:

```
size_t fwrite(
    const void *restrict buffer, //pointer to the first object in the array to be written 
    size_t size, //size of each object 
    size_t count, //the number of the objects to be written
    FILE *restrict stream //pointer to the output stream
);
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) says the following:

> Writes count of objects from the given array buffer to the output stream stream.
>
> The objects are written **as if** by reinterpreting each object as an array of unsigned char and calling fputc size times for each object to write those unsigned chars into stream, in order.
> ...

**Note:** the parameter `buffer` is of type `void*`, that means, only an address of a region (block) of memory is passed to `fwrite`, no type information whatsoever. In other words, `fwrite` does not know (care) of what is stored at the specific location.

Answer (score 1):

C allows you to `memcpy` any object with an address or treat any such object as an array of a character type (`char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`).

That is, `fwrite` can do:

```
size_t fwrite(
    const void *restrict buffer, //pointer to the first object in the array to be written 
    size_t size, //size of each object 
    size_t count, //the number of the objects to be written
    FILE *restrict stream //pointer to the output stream
) {
  //...
   memcpy(streams_internal_buffer, buffer, size);
  //...
}
```

or (perhaps less efficiently, though a compiler might recognize such loops):

```
//...
for(size_t *p=(char*)buffer, *end=(char*)buffer+size; p!=end;) *target++ = *p;
//...
```

Optimizing compilers need to treat memcpy-calls such loops magically because of their strict-aliasing implications.
They may generate for them either inline code or a call to a real `memcpy` function.

Libc `memcpy` implementations tend to be beneficial for large-range copying and are written in assembly or in specially annotated C (e.g., `attribute((may_alias))`) or with small-fixed-sized `memcpy` calls that must be locally (for the given compiler) known not to generate a real (recursive) call). The aim of such a real memcpy implementation to copy via larger (word-sized) aligned chunks rather than char-by-char.